# Check the number of sundays between two dates

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I am trying to calculate the number of sundays there are between 2 dates.

If possible i'd like to avoid counting the first sunday if it's less than 7 days after the first date. See it as counting the number of full weeks between the two dates.

That's what i have done so far, i appreciate the help of more experienced developers here!

```
let date1 = datePicker.date
let date2 = NSDate()

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .short
formatter.allowedUnits = [.day]
formatter.maximumUnitCount = 2   

let string = formatter.string (from: date1 as Date, to: date2 as Date)
```

Comment: What about locales where the start of the week in Monday? Do you really want to count Sundays or do you really want to calculate the number of full weeks between two dates? If the latter, are you trying to count the number of full rows on a calendar or simply the number of days between the two dates modulus 7? Please update your question with more specific details about your actual goal.

Comment: BTW - what does the code you posted in your question have to do with calculating the number of Sundays or weeks between two dates? And why use `NSDate` in Swift? Just use `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by calculating when the first Sunday after the start date is and then calculate the number of days between the next Sunday and the end date and divide by 7

```
func sundays(between dateFrom: Date, and dateTo: Date) -> Int {
    let nextSunday = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .weekday, value: 1, of: dateFrom)!
    let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: nextSunday, to: dateTo).day!

    return days < 7 ? 0 : days / 7 + 1
}
```